# Diff linux kernel modules

Tags: linux-kernel, diff, kernel-module

Is it possible to diff 2 kernel modules so that if they are binary compatible (minus the modversion and version strings that change in the header part), they can be considered equivalent like one would do with elfdiff for binaries?

I looked online a bit and couldn't find any evidence or ways to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What is definition of 'binary compatibility' you are using for kernel modules?

Comment: Everything in the elf except the sections that are specific to kernel modules like _version, _modversion, etc. I'm thinking that I'll just write my own in python using objdump and go through all sections and avoid the ones I want to avoid.

Comment: It's hard to understand the real use case for that.